# how can I give a normal user write access to a network interface?

Tags: networking, sudo

I have a program that reads and writes packets to/from network interfaces, and normally I would add myself in the sudoers file and run the program like this:

```
sudo ./bridge
```

But now I need multiple users to run this program, but without giving them sudo rights, such that they could run the program like this:

```
./bridge
```

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this? I am running Scientific Linux 6.1 on a 64bit platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sudo rule to allow that user to run your script. Run `visudo` and add something like this to the `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults!/path/to/bridge env_reset
alice, bill  ALL = (root) /path/to/bridge
```

Note that his allows the users to pass any argument to the `/path/to/bridge` program. Add `""` at the end of the line to forbid passing any arguments.

For easier user management, you may prefer to define a group of users who are allowed to control the bridge. Replace `alice, bill` by `%bridgers` where `bridgers` is the name of the group.

Inside the `bridge` program, `$SUDO_UID` is the user ID of the user who invoked `sudo`. If the program requires that user to be in the `USER` variable, write a small wrapper shell script that sets `USER=$SUDO_UID`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed something like $SUDO_USER to get the username of the person that used sudo to start the program.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict in [sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) the commands that are allowed to run with sudo.

Write a small script `./bridge` that call `sudo ./real-bridge` and give the users the right to run ./real-bridge as root via sudo.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I don't want to give the users sudo rights; this would mess up some things in the program which are based on the $USER enviroment variable, not to mention I give them unlimited rights in the system :)

Comment: @Claudiu I just wanted to get sure, that you know that you can limit the commands which can be run by sudo. If the allowed commands have no security issues, you would not provide unlimited rights to the users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it works with eth devices, but this people do with tun devices.

```
$ tail -n1 /etc/udev/rules.d/20-kvm.rules 
KERNEL=="tun",          NAME="net/%k", GROUP="mygoodusers", MODE="0660"
```

See - GROUP="mygoodusers", MODE="0660" - on that line. Of course you have to put each user into that group.

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

but until reboot you have to chmod/chown manually.

Comment: So, I guess I should put "eth" instead of "tun"? And "eth0"/"eth1"/"eth2" instead of "net/%k"?

Comment: _but until reboot you have to chmod/chown manually._ By the way, what are the files on which I should chown/chmod?

Comment: The example with tun device doesn't work with real network adapters. Use sudo for your problem, you can define command alias and group alias as well in /etc/sudoers, plus you will get logging for each usages of sudo ;)