# udev rule to give user full access to network interface can0

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, udev

I am trying to give permission to a user to perform the same operations as root on the network device `can0`, such as bringing it up or down.  My first idea was to set the group and/or owner of the device to my user and a group I belong to.

Here's what `udevadm info -ap $(udevadm info -q path -p /sys/class/net/can0)` shows before setting a udev rule:

```bsh
$ udevadm info -ap $(udevadm info -q path -p /sys/class/net/can0)
  looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0/net/can0':
    KERNEL=="can0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="net"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{netdev_group}=="0"
...
  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f204000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.0':
    KERNELS=="spi0.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="spi"
    DRIVERS=="mcp251x"
```

And here's the rule I tried (in `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-can.rules`):

```
KERNELS=="spi0.0", SUBSYSTEMS=="spi", DRIVERS=="mcp251x", GROUP="can", OWNER="<myuser>"
```

A `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -p /sys/class/net/can0)` reports the owner and group should be set correctly:

```
...
OWNER 1001 /etc/udev/rules.d/50-can.rules:7
GROUP 1003 /etc/udev/rules.d/50-can.rules:7
...
```

However after reloading the rules (`udevadm control -R`) and a reboot, I still cannot bring `can0` up or down as a user:

```bsh
$ ip link set can0 down
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I know this rule is matched correctly because I can change the name of the interface by setting the `NAME` property.

I suspect the problem might have to do with the fact that I can't find a `can0` interface under `/dev`, which might indicate that there is no character/block device for it and programs (such as `ip`) don't access the device through traditional unix ownership/permissions.  If that's correct, how can I accomplish this with udev (namely, giving my user full permissions to `can0`)?

Note: I saw similar questions such as [how can I give a normal user write access to a network interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/how-can-i-give-a-normal-user-write-access-to-a-network-interface), but their solution is to use sudo.  I'd rather do this with udev only, but I'll use this as a last resort.

Comment: Once the interface is created (maybe with the help of *udev*) it's behaving as any other interface, and *udev* doesn't have a word to say about it. You can't achieve your goal through *udev*. An interface configuration requires root access or CAP_NET_ADMIN or any tool (with those privileges) available to the user. sudo, NetworkManager, ...

Comment: I see, thanks for the info about CAP_NET_ADMIN, I'm looking into it now.  I did a preliminary attempt by doing a `sudo setcap cap_net_admin+ie /bin/ip` (which seemed to work), but I still got `Operation not permitted`.  More research needed I guess.

Comment: @A.B OK I got it by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user carefully.  Your comment gave me exacly what I wanted to do (bring can0 up/down without going through sudo).  Would you like to put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's fine if your answer it yourself. I gave pointers but didn't know what would work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Following clue from @A.B I ended up using `libpam` (`pam_cap.so`) to add the capability `CAP_NET_ADMIN` to my user's `inheritable` set during login (and ssh), then added the same capability to `/bin/ip`'s `inheritable` and `permitted` sets.  I can now bring network interfaces up or down as the user, and without relying on `sudo`.

The way to do this is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user